# Change effect of image without re-build docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am beginner in docker. When I build and run image I can not get any change which I have modified (code) after build Image. In details:

```
docker build -t imageName . -f Dockerfile
docker-compose up -d
```

By following this command I can build and run Image. **If there need any modification I have to build again. But I don't want to do that repeatedly for development purpose** . Here is my .yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  proj_service:
    container_name: demo_proj
    image: my_demo_proj:2.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:80
    networks:
      - demo_proj-newtork
    env_file:
      - ./demo_proj.env
networks:
    demo_proj-newtork:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.1

WORKDIR usr/src/my_app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this using volumes in Docker. If you want help with that, can you put your Dockerfile as well?

Comment: Sure. I updated my question

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. If you try to run this in your local machine (not using docker), and you change the code while the app is being served, would it reflect in the browser? (If so, I think  I can try to help you, otherwise, someone who knows PHP should help you I guess)

Comment: Ok , I updated it for python now. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally what you need to do is to create a docker volume so that your source files will become visible to the container.

I am guessing you have your source files inside `src` directory and your directory structure is something like below:

```
my_app
|
|-- src
|-- docker-compose.yml
```

Try updating your docker-compose file like below:

```sh
version: '2'

services:
  proj_service:
    container_name: demo_proj
    image: my_demo_proj:2.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:80
    networks:
      - demo_proj-newtork
    env_file:
      - ./demo_proj.env
    volumes:
      # Path on your code in your machine, relative to the Compose file
      - ./src:/usr/src/my_app/src
networks:
    demo_proj-newtork:
```